# How to launch an iOS app without using URL scheme from another iOS app? There's an app which can do this, how?

Tags: ios, launch, url-scheme

All the answers found from [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) said that you can't launch an app without using Url Scheme, but I found an app can launch apps even these apps didn't have URL schemes (for example, my app which is published on App Store don't have URL scheme, but it can launch my app). I want to know how to do this?

- That app works in both iOS 8 & iOS 9, so it doesn't use the new iOS 9 API
- iPhone is not Jailbreak
- I have searched many apps, only this app can do that

Comment: I don't think that is possible to do with all apps. One thing I know, is if the app is using Facebook SDK they automatically have "fb" deeplink. But which App are you talking about?